# select the SECOND highest value for each group in mySQL 5

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, max, min

this code gets id and latest timestamps for each ID

```
select id, max(start_time) as start1, max(end_time) as end1 from table group by id
```

how do I get the second highest timestamps as start2 and end2?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  For instance, for a given id, are the rows tiled by the start/end times?

Answer (score 1):

One option uses correlated subqueries:

```
select 
    id, 
    max(start_time) as start1, 
    max(end_time) as end1,
    (
        select t1.start_time
        from mytable t1
        where t1.id = t.id
        order by t1.start_time desc
        limit 1, 1
    ) start2,
    (
        select t1.end_time
        from mytable t1
        where t1.id = t.id
        order by t1.end_time desc
        limit 1, 1
    ) end2
from mytable t
group by id
```

Comment: what if I want to extend it to nth highest?

Comment: @ignacio.natas: just change the first argument to `limit`. `limit 2, 1` gives you the third highest, and so on.